# Facebook Api V2.2 Fql query

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm currently using the Facebook Javascript Sdk version 2.2 and the api call below executes without any problems.
But wasn't **Fql deprecated** with version 2.1?
And the most important question **will this query also work in the future**?

```
FB.api(
   {
       method: "fql.query",
       query: "select first_name from user where uid=me()"
   },
   function (response) {
       console.log(response);
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not using the Graph API with the method call to `fql.query`, but the deprecated REST API, which will only work until April 30th 2015.

The correct endpoint would be

```
/fql?q={query}
```

which is only usable up to v2.1.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql#read

Comment: But there are features in Fql which are not available using Graph Api. Will these features just vanish at the end of april?

Comment: If you have a v2.0 app, this will work until August 7th 2016. If your app is >=v2.1, it will stop working on April 30th 2015. Like I said, you're using a deprecated endpoint anyway.

Comment: Some of the FQL is still accessible & usable without App ID via HTTP POST, for example obtaining like count from a page. However, this may be changed at any time...